# Should I be passing around entitiy models as parameters? (using RedBean ORM)

Tags: php, orm, entity, service-layer, redbean

I'm just beginning to experiment with the Slim framework and RedBean ORM in PHP.

Let's say I have a `CommentService` registered with Slim's Dependency Injection Container. Also, I have a data model named `Comment_Model` which is used by RedBean to represent comments stored in a database.

Now, from my route/controller, I want to add a new comment to the database. This is where I'm a bit confused - what would be the "best practice" way of passing information from the route/controller to the service method?

I can think of at least three different ways to do this;

**1 - Use an instance of `Comment_Model` to supply the data:**

```
class CommentService {

    public function add(\App\Data\Model\Model_Comment $comment){
        // Let the ORM persist the data        
    }

}
```

This feels a bit like abusing the data model entity class though - isn't it meant to be instantiated by the ORM, not as a convenience feature to pass around new, unpersisted data?

**2 - Separate parameters**

```
class CommentService {

    public function add($userId, $message, $replyToId){
        // Let the ORM create a proper data model and persist the data 
    }

}
```

It works when there are only three parameters, but for something more complex than a comment it could easily get out of hand...

**3 - Create a Data Transfer Object**

```
class CommentDTO{
    public $userId;
    public $message;
    public $replyToId;
}


class CommentService {

    public function add(\App\Data\DTO\CommentDTO $comment){
        // Let the ORM create a proper data model and persist the data
    }

}
```

Isn't it a bit overkill to create a DTO for local use?

Are there any hard rights and wrongs here? What is the "normal" way to do things like this?

Comment: I think your first option is ideal.  I pretty much use the same model of Request/Service/Model and so far so good, although I'm using the Eloquent db model rather than RedBean. I like keeping the service methods as simple as possible and allow the controllers to only handle calls to the service based on the request.

Comment: @Rob Thanks, I ended up going with the models in the end. At first I started out using DTO's but it turned out to add unnecessary complexity for something that is much more elegantly done using models.